# Route www link to non-www link in .net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

It seems with the built in friendly routing library in .NET MVC, it would allow us to do something like this.

In case it's not obvious what I want to with the built in stuff in .NET MVC, I want to a url starting with www to be automatically redirected to a non-www url using the MVC framework.

Comment: It's important to be aware that if you don't use a www (or some other subdomain) then all cookies will be submitted to every subdomain amd you won't be able to have a cookie-less subdomain for serving static content thus reducing the amount of data sent back and forth between the browser and the server. Something you might later come to regret: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/1637428313

Comment: Complementing @Sam comment: For a little better understanding http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do the 301 redirect from the www to the not-www. I prefer to keep this redirection logic at the ASP.NET level (i.e. in my app) in some projects, but others require better performing things, like IIS7 url rewriting.

It was [discussed on the ASP.NET forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1324018.aspx) and I chose to use a WwwFilter on each controller. This has worked for me, no issues.

Comment: Have deleted my previous answer as this seems to address the user's specific question better, i.e., how to do URL redirection in an ASP.NET MVC-centric way. Whereas I think URL redirection is best handled outside of ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [IIS 7 URL Rewriting module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

You can setup it from IIS or just place in your `web.config` the following under `<system.webServer>`:

### www to non-www

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Canonical" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www[.](.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Alternatively you can make this redirection on `global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    if (Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Location", 
            String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host.Substring(4), Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            );
        Response.StatusCode = 301;
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

But remeber what @Sam said, [look here for more info](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/).

---

### non-www to www

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Canonical" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([a-z]+[.]net)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Make a regex pattern to match your host and use `{C:0}` `1, 2, ..., N` to get the matching groups.

Comment: you don't have to crate new RedirectController, can user HomeControler and  routes.MapRoute("Root", "Home", new { controller = "Home", action = "Home" });

Answer (score 0):

try to add this into your ***Global.asax*** :

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://YourSite.com"))
    {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://YourSite.com","http://www.YourSite.com"));
    }
```

**it works and tested.**