# how to change pefix in the url using web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, web.config-transform

Currently my website is functioning both with a www prefix and without. I want every page should redirect with www prefix only for search engine optimization (SEO).

The changes should not impact on local development environment (localhost)

How can I do that on Web.Config file?

Any another approaches to accomplish this?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885581/add-www-prefix-to-url

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem using the below changes on web.config file.

```
 <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.com$" />
      </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="h t t p : //www.mydomain.com/{R:0}" />
  </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```