# How do I enforce www on an IIS hosted website?

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

My site is hosted on IIS, I need to enforce the browser to use www prefix.

I've installed the [Url Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and my rule is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
              <rule name="Add WWW" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)$" />
              <conditions>
                 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)(.*)$" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
           </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

from [IIS7 URL Rewrite - Add "www" prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207059/iis7-url-rewrite-add-www-prefix)

But I cannot work out how to maintain ssl

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer or provide some feedback if I've misinterpreted your scenario or just plain got it wrong :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the protocol in the input:

```
<rule name="Enforce WWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://(?!www)(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

`{C:1}` will contain the protocol and `{C:2}` will have your domain and anything else.

<sub>([source](http://madskristensen.net/post/url-rewrite-and-the-www-subdomain))</sub>