# How to create a global rewrite rule to redirect all root domain request to www?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

The target IIS serves multiple domains via multiple sites and host header binding.
So far when a new site (domain) was added I could create a specific rule for that domain to redirect example.com requests to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

```
<rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions >
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" 
    <-- it is OK to hardcode https, because http->https rewrite rule also in effect --!>, 
    url="https://www.example./{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

**Question**

Besides I am not sure the rule/condition/action above is entirely correct, now I would like to improve the solution to one universal rewrite rule.
How can I add an universal global rule what will apply to all (future) domains, and redirects anysld.anytld/anyremainingpathandqueryandwhoknowswhat to [www.anysld.anytld/anyremainingpathandqueryandwhoknowswhat](http://www.anysld.anytld/anyremainingpathandqueryandwhoknowswhat)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly code from another SO question should help you. [Take a look at IIS7 URL Rewrite - Add "www" prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207059/iis7-url-rewrite-add-www-prefix). Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use global rules to redirect requests to www in all root domain, you can try the following global rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <globalRules>
         <rule name="Add www" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)(.*)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{C:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
          </rule>
    </globalRules>
</rewrite>
```