# How to 301 redirect in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, search-engine, http-status-code-301

I am trying to implement URL redirect for the website rather than doing it page by page. I want to do it in the global.asax file. Below is the code i have defined.

I want to have http://website.net as my main url & want to have a permanent URL redirect if someone types in http://www.website.net.

Unfortunately it is not working for the live website. Can anyone point out the problem in the code. The code doesn't generate any error.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://website.net"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://website.net", "http://www.website.net"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Main problem: Your're doing the above stuff in `Application_Start` - which is only executed once. You should hook up with each request. Try this:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on every request

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://website.net"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://website.net", "http://www.website.net"));
    }

}
```

An even better approach would be to use URL rewriting, which can be configured from within `Web.Config`:

[Microsoft rewriting module - Force www on url Or remove www from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153670/microsoft-rewriting-module-force-www-on-url-or-remove-www-from-url)

Comment: Oops My mistake. Should have noticed... I am planning to implement url routing rather than rewriting and i had issue with rewriting due to the structure and no. of query-string in certain pages. Appreciate your reply.  Thanks

Comment: It is better to use StartsWith instead of  Conatins like this : if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith("http://website.net"))

Comment: @keivankashani No it's not better. Some urls start with http or https and your method does not work in this cases.

Answer (score 13):

If using IIS 7 or higher, the simplest solution is to use the httpRedirect element in your web.config.

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
     <add wildcard="/MyOldAspFile.aspx" destination="/MyNewFile.aspx" />
     <add wildcard="/MyOldHtmlFile.html" destination="/MyNewFile.aspx" />
</httpRedirect>
```

This method is very powerful, for example if you have changed the domain but the pages are the same, you have just to add:

```
<system.webServer> 
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" childOnly="true" destination="http://www.mynewdomain.com/" /> 
</system.webServer>
```

I wrote a small article here: [ASP.NET 301 permanent redirects: the best solution](http://www.idea-r.it/Blog.aspx/asp-net-301-redirect)

Answer (score 9):

Version 4 of .NET actually has an improved function for single page implementation - the [redirectpermanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx).

`Response.RedirectPermanent(NEW_URL);`

Answer (score 5):

Building on previous correct and helpful answers, here are a couple specific examples. Assuming you want to delete the old page (as I did), there are a couple of options.

**OPTION 1: Modify the Global.asax**

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add permanent redirection for retired pages
        if (Request.Url.LocalPath.ToLower().StartsWith("/[OLD PAGE NAME]"))
        {
            Response.RedirectPermanent("/[NEW PAGE NAME]", false);
        }
    }
```

**OPTION 2: Modify the web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent">
        <add wildcard="/[OLD PAGE NAME]" destination="/[NEW PAGE NAME]" />
    </httpRedirect>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you didn't know what is application domain name ,use something like this

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).Contains("localhost"))return;
        var leftPartOfUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToLower();
        if (leftPartOfUrl.StartsWith("http") && leftPartOfUrl.Split('.').Length == 1)
        {
            var fullUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 301;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", fullUrl.Insert(fullUrl.IndexOf("://", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 3, "www."));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```