# How to 301 permanent redirect old URLs to new ones?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, permanent

My website's URL has been changed, and I want to implement 301 permanent redirection. The home page URL is the same, but inner page URLs have been changed. Here are some old and new URLs of my website-

- Old URL- http://www.emulateinfotech.com/about-us.aspx
- New URL-  http://www.emulateinfotech.com/about-us
- Old URL- http://www.emulateinfotech.com/portfolio.aspx
- New URL- http://www.emulateinfotech.com/portfolio
- Old URL- http://www.emulateinfotech.com/contact-us.aspx
- New URL- http://www.emulateinfotech.com/contact-us

Can anyone tell me the 301 permanent redirection code from old to new URL?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what you have searched for before asking and why the obvious Google hits are not allowing you to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [301 redirect in asp.net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673303/301-redirect-in-asp-net-4-0)

Comment: Maybe a redirect with an apache .htaccess will do the trick. But I'm not an expert at that field... here is a simple example
`Redirect /old-index.html http://www.my-domain.de/dir/new-index.html` It also can redirect RegEx so maybe you can look if there is a .aspx on the end and then redirect