# Prepend www second level domain rewrite

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting

I'd like to add www to every domain name of a website.
These are the domains I like to include:

- domain.com
- domain.nl
- domain.de
- domain.co.in

What I have so far is:

```
<rule name="Prepend www to 2nd level domain names" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url=".*" />
           <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$" />
                  <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="{C:2}://www.{C:1}/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```

This works for all the domains, except the co.in. I'm not sure how I can also include TLD's with more than one '.'?

Comment: i think you might want to add the 'regex' tag to your question. the pattern is regex i believe and someone who can rewrite your regex in the sections above may help you find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.*" />`

A longer Version how it works is here: [Forwarding http://mydomain.com/ctrlr/act/val to http://WWW.mydomain.com/ctrlr/act/val](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476934/forwarding-http-mydomain-com-ctrlr-act-val-to-http-www-mydomain-com-ctrlr-ac/1476986#1476986)

Which essentially is the same as i wrote above.
Here is the rule adapted to support TLD

```
<rule name="Add WWW prefix" >
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.{C:1}/{R:1}"
          redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: That is not working. If you add www. in front it is redirected to www.www.domain.com

Comment: But the pattern is "starts with Domain" not "starts with WWW"

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to configure this. I also tried this pattern but it didn't work either: ^[^\sw\.@/]([0-9a-zA-Z\-\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+\.)(co.in|de|com|nl|CO.IN|DE|COM|NL)

Comment: I added some more information to the answer - this should work.