# Redirecting http://example.com to http://www.example.com

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, dns, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Route www link to non-www link in .net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293597/route-www-link-to-non-www-link-in-net-mvc)

Hey,

I want my website to be accessed only on the www sub domain.
How can i do it?

I'm using ASP .NET 3.5, C#, IIS 7, But i host it on GoDaddy so no access to IIS, just FTP.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: You should be able to access your IIS settings.  I am not exactly sure the reason you even want to do this.  Of course the alternative is get a better host where you have more control.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. He is not using MVC.

Comment: The answer is the same... But whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rewrite module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) which is available on Godaddy.

You can setup it from IIS or just place in your `web.config` the following under `<system.webServer>`:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Canonical" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([a-z]+[.]com)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Alternatively you can make this redirection on global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Location", 
            String.Format("{0}://www.{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            );
        Response.StatusCode = 301;
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: I Hate web.config ! lol
I never understand where to place what, the <rewrite> should be nested inside something else? or just inside <configuration> ?

Comment: @Danpe `<system.webServer>`. I recommend using the rewrite module instead of the alternative method I showed above.

Comment: I get: `Warning 2 The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'rewrite'.`

Comment: @Danpe I also get that. I don't know if there is a namespace that is required by this module... But I've been using this for a while and I didn't have any problems. `web.config` transforms works just normal.

Comment: Yup, works perfectly i just hate random Warnings.
Anyway you look like a ReWrite module pro :P
So how can i change /Auction.aspx?id=1 to /Auction/1/
:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog post by ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx). You'll have to manually add the rule(s) to your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an apache web server, add this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} .
RewriteCond %{http_host}!^www\.example\.com [NC]
rewriterule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The author is using IIS 7 and ASP.NET 3.5.  Furthermore I don't believe GoDaddy does not recongize the .htaccess file.